# No module named ctypes using ironPython?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, importerror

I am calling Python method from C# using **IronPython 2.6 CTP for .NET 4.0 Beta 2**.
I have included the following libraries:

```
IronPython.dll
IronPython.Modules.dll
Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Debugging.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
```

**Python Code that I am invoking**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes

class EAHashingAlgorithm():

    def __init__(self):
        # shift amounts in each round
        self.r1Shifts = [ 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22 ]
        self.r2Shifts = [ 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20 ]
        self.r3Shifts = [ 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23 ]
        self.r4Shifts = [ 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21 ]

        self.hexChars = "0123456789abcdef"

    def zero_fill_right_shit(self, data, bits):
        return (data & 0xffffffff) >> bits

    def num2hex(self, num):
        '''
            Convert a decimal number to hexadecimal
        '''
        temp = ''
        for i in range(0, 4):
            x = self.hexChars[ ( num >> (i * 8 + 4) ) & 0x0F ]
            y = self.hexChars[ ( num >> (i * 8) ) & 0x0F ]
            temp += (x + y)

        return temp

    def chunkMessage(self, string):
        # TODO: ctypes.c_int32() in this method
        nblk = (( len(string) + 8) >> 6) + 1
        blks = [0] * (nblk * 16)

        for i in range(0, len(string)):
            blks[i >> 2] |= ord(string[i]) << ((i % 4) * 8)

        i = i + 1

        blks[i >> 2] |= 0x80 << ((i % 4) * 8)
        blks[nblk * 16 - 2] = len(string) * 8

        return blks

    def add(self, x, y):
        lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF)
        msw = (ctypes.c_int32(x >> 16).value) + (ctypes.c_int32(y >> 16).value) + (ctypes.c_int32(lsw >> 16).value)
        return ctypes.c_int32( (ctypes.c_int32(msw << 16).value) | (lsw & 0xFFFF) ).value

    # Bitwise rotate 32bit num to left
    def bitwiseRotate(self, x, c):
        return ctypes.c_int32( ctypes.c_int32(x << c).value | self.zero_fill_right_shit(x, 32 - c) ).value

    # Basic MD5 operations
    def cmn(self, q, a, b, x, s, t):
        z1 = self.add(a, q)
        z2 = self.add(x, t) 
        a1 = self.add(z1, z2)

        x1 = self.bitwiseRotate(a1, s)
        return self.add(x1, b)

    def md5_f(self, a, b, c, d, x, s, t):
        return self.cmn( ctypes.c_int32((b & c) | ((~b) & d)).value, a, b, x, s, t )

    def md5_g(self, a, b, c, d, x, s, t):
        return self.cmn( ctypes.c_int32((b & d) | (c & (~d))).value, a, b, x, s, t )

    def md5_h(self, a, b, c, d, x, s, t):
        return self.cmn( ctypes.c_int32(b ^ c ^ d).value, a, b, x, s, t )

    def md5_i(self, a, b, c, d, x, s, t):
        return self.cmn( ctypes.c_int32(c ^ (b | (~d))).value, a, b, x, s, t )

    def EAHash(self, string):
        x = self.chunkMessage(string)

        a = 1732584193
        b = -271733879
        c = -1732584194
        d = 271733878

        for i in range(0, 16, 16):
            tempA = a
            tempB = b
            tempC = c
            tempD = d

            # F
            a = self.md5_f(a, b, c, d, x[i+0], self.r1Shifts[0], -680876936)
            d = self.md5_f(d, a, b, c, x[i+1], self.r1Shifts[1], -389564586)
            c = self.md5_f(c, d, a, b, x[i+2], self.r1Shifts[2], 606105819)
            b = self.md5_f(b, c, d, a, x[i+3], self.r1Shifts[3], -1044525330)

            a = self.md5_f(a, b, c, d, x[i+4], self.r1Shifts[4], -176418897)
            d = self.md5_f(d, a, b, c, x[i+5], self.r1Shifts[5], 1200080426)
            c = self.md5_f(c, d, a, b, x[i+6], self.r1Shifts[6], -1473231341)
            b = self.md5_f(b, c, d, a, x[i+7], self.r1Shifts[7], -45705983)

            a = self.md5_f(a, b, c, d, x[i+8], self.r1Shifts[8], 1770035416)
            d = self.md5_f(d, a, b, c, x[i+9], self.r1Shifts[9], -1958414417)
            c = self.md5_f(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], self.r1Shifts[10], -42063)
            b = self.md5_f(b, c, d, a, x[i+11], self.r1Shifts[11], -1990404162)

            a = self.md5_f(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], self.r1Shifts[12], 1804603682)
            d = self.md5_f(d, a, b, c, x[i+13], self.r1Shifts[13], -40341101)
            c = self.md5_f(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], self.r1Shifts[14], -1502002290)
            b = self.md5_f(b, c, d, a, x[i+15], self.r1Shifts[15], 1236535329)

            # G
            a = self.md5_g(a, b, c, d, x[i+1], self.r2Shifts[0], -165796510)
            d = self.md5_g(d, a, b, c, x[i+6], self.r2Shifts[1], -1069501632)
            c = self.md5_g(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], self.r2Shifts[2], 643717713)
            b = self.md5_g(b, c, d, a, x[i+0], self.r2Shifts[3], -373897302)

            a = self.md5_g(a, b, c, d, x[i+5], self.r2Shifts[4], -701558691)
            d = self.md5_g(d, a, b, c, x[i+10], self.r2Shifts[5], 38016083)
            c = self.md5_g(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], self.r2Shifts[6], -660478335)
            b = self.md5_g(b, c, d, a, x[i+4], self.r2Shifts[7], -405537848)

            a = self.md5_g(a, b, c, d, x[i+9], self.r2Shifts[8], 568446438)
            d = self.md5_g(d, a, b, c, x[i+14], self.r2Shifts[9], -1019803690)
            c = self.md5_g(c, d, a, b, x[i+3], self.r2Shifts[10], -187363961)
            b = self.md5_g(b, c, d, a, x[i+8], self.r2Shifts[11], 1163531501)

            a = self.md5_g(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], self.r2Shifts[12], -1444681467)
            d = self.md5_g(d, a, b, c, x[i+2], self.r2Shifts[13], -51403784)
            c = self.md5_g(c, d, a, b, x[i+7], self.r2Shifts[14], 1735328473)
            b = self.md5_g(b, c, d, a, x[i+12], self.r2Shifts[15], -1926607734)

            # H
            a = self.md5_h(a, b, c, d, x[i+5], self.r3Shifts[0], -378558)
            d = self.md5_h(d, a, b, c, x[i+8], self.r3Shifts[1], -2022574463)
            # line below uses self.r2Shifts[2] where as MD5 would use self.r3Shifts[2]
            c = self.md5_h(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], self.r2Shifts[2], 1839030562)
            b = self.md5_h(b, c, d, a, x[i+14], self.r3Shifts[3], -35309556)

            a = self.md5_h(a, b, c, d, x[i+1], self.r3Shifts[4], -1530992060)
            d = self.md5_h(d, a, b, c, x[i+4], self.r3Shifts[5], 1272893353)
            c = self.md5_h(c, d, a, b, x[i+7], self.r3Shifts[6], -155497632)
            b = self.md5_h(b, c, d, a, x[i+10], self.r3Shifts[7], -1094730640)

            a = self.md5_h(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], self.r3Shifts[8], 681279174)
            d = self.md5_h(d, a, b, c, x[i+0], self.r3Shifts[9], -358537222)
            c = self.md5_h(c, d, a, b, x[i+3], self.r3Shifts[10], -722521979)
            b = self.md5_h(b, c, d, a, x[i+6], self.r3Shifts[11], 76029189)

            a = self.md5_h(a, b, c, d, x[i+9], self.r3Shifts[12], -640364487)
            d = self.md5_h(d, a, b, c, x[i+12], self.r3Shifts[13], -421815835)
            c = self.md5_h(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], self.r3Shifts[14], 530742520)
            b = self.md5_h(b, c, d, a, x[i+2], self.r3Shifts[15], -995338651)

            # I
            a = self.md5_i(a, b, c, d, x[i+0], self.r4Shifts[0], -198630844)
            d = self.md5_i(d, a, b, c, x[i+7], self.r4Shifts[1], 1126891415)
            c = self.md5_i(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], self.r4Shifts[2], -1416354905)
            b = self.md5_i(b, c, d, a, x[i+5], self.r4Shifts[3], -57434055)

            a = self.md5_i(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], self.r4Shifts[4], 1700485571)
            d = self.md5_i(d, a, b, c, x[i+3], self.r4Shifts[5], -1894986606)
            c = self.md5_i(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], self.r4Shifts[6], -1051523)
            b = self.md5_i(b, c, d, a, x[i+1], self.r4Shifts[7], -2054922799)

            a = self.md5_i(a, b, c, d, x[i+8], self.r4Shifts[8], 1873313359)
            d = self.md5_i(d, a, b, c, x[i+15], self.r4Shifts[9], -30611744)
            c = self.md5_i(c, d, a, b, x[i+6], self.r4Shifts[10], -1560198380)
            b = self.md5_i(b, c, d, a, x[i+13], self.r4Shifts[11], 1309151649)

            a = self.md5_i(a, b, c, d, x[i+4], self.r4Shifts[12], -145523070)
            d = self.md5_i(d, a, b, c, x[i+11], self.r4Shifts[13], -1120210379)
            c = self.md5_i(c, d, a, b, x[i+2], self.r4Shifts[14], 718787259)
            b = self.md5_i(b, c, d, a, x[i+9], self.r4Shifts[15], -343485551)
            # This line is doubled for some reason, line below is not in the MD5 version
            b = self.md5_i(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 9], self.r4Shifts[15], -343485551)

            a = self.add(a, tempA)
            b = self.add(b, tempB)
            c = self.add(c, tempC)
            d = self.add(d, tempD)

        return self.num2hex(a) + self.num2hex(b) + self.num2hex(c) + self.num2hex(d)
```

**C# code to call the method:**
`eaHash(...)`

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("EAHashingAlgorithm.py");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
source.Execute(scope);

dynamic eaHash = scope.GetVariable("EAHashingAlgorithm");
dynamic hash = eaHash();
this.answer = hash.EAHash(_answer);
```

**Error recieved**
`ImportError: No module named ctypes`

Comment: What version of IronPython are you using?

Comment: it's `ctypes` not `ctype`

Comment: Yes, I am using ctypes as an import..refer to the .py code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the IronPython standard library is available as well, as `ctypes` requires some pure-Python files as well. Add a call to `engine.SetSearchPaths(new [] { "path/to/Lib" });` that points to the library. If you're using the installer, it's probably under `C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7`; in the zip file, it's in  `Lib`.

If you're distributing and application, it makes most sense to use a folder relative to your executable; `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` may be useful for that.

Answer (score 1):

> I keep getting the error there is no such module named as ctype...help anyone?

Well, first of all, the module is called `ctypes`, not `ctype`.

But, more importantly, `ctypes` doesn't exist in IronPython until version 2.6.

That includes early 2.6 alphas, and apparently also the 2.6 CTPs for .NET 4 (which were forked from the early alphas). If you want to know exactly when it made it into 2.6 (which beta, etc.), that information is probably available somewhere, but you really shouldn't care. Use a final 2.6 or later.

If you can't do that, there is at least one third-party implementation [here](http://blog.jdhardy.ca/2009/04/ctypes-for-ironpython.html) that you might be able to use.

Comment: I am using IronPython 2.6 CTP for .NET 4.0 Beta 2

Comment: @faizanjehangir: Can you upgrade to 2.6.0 final (or later)? You really shouldn't be using a CTP (especially a CTP for a beta environment) for real code in general. But more specifically, the .NET 4.0 CTPs were forked from an early alpha of 2.6, which doesn't have all of the changes, which apparently includes not having `ctypes`.

Comment: The exception arises whenever I am importing ctypes in the .py file. Else it works fine...